# Devexpress TimeEditControl: How to get selected portion of Hour or Minute in the control?

Tags: c#, devexpress

i want to change the incremental for hour and minute, by whenever click on the hour/minute text portion and click the spin button increase/decrease the hour/minute respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you must know by default ASPxTimeEdit does not allow do like this. The previous suggested approach is a kind of a "hack".The current issue is caused by the fact that ASPxTimeEdit executes an internal inc/dec action according to the current caret position (hours, seconds, days).
 You cannot cancel this action on the client-side ButtonClick event properly since this event is raised before an internal action is executed.

A possible solution to this issue is to hide standard spin buttons (SpinButtons.ShowIncrementButtons="false") and create custom buttons with required logic.
refer to this link http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/B200804.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
function ApplySeed(s,e) {
  var date = s.GetDate();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var inputElement = s.GetInputElement();

  if (inputElement.selectionStart == 3 && inputElement.selectionEnd == 6) {
      date.setMinutes(minutes + 10); \\if user in minute portion 
  }
  if (inputElement.selectionEnd == 3 && inputElement.selectionStart == 0) {
      date.setHours(hours + 1); \\if user in hour portion
  }

  s.SetDate(date);
}
```